# Is there a specific age timeline in Detective Conan?

Tags: detective-conan

Do the characters in Detective Conan age according to time? I am asking how the characters age, or if the characters age at all.

Comment: No, I am specifically asking as to how or if the characters aged in the series. Hold on, I'll edit it slightly.

Answer (score 1):

No I believe it is one of those shows that has years go by but they remain the same age like Pokemon ash never ages even though he should be 18 now and not 10